Cómo puedo contabilizar los carácteres con tilde y letra ñ con el comando awk?
Sé que los carácteres con tilde y la letra "ñ" no se llevan muy bien con Linux, pero me ha surgido una duda que seguro me aclaráis los cracks que hay de Linux en esta comunidad.
De un conjunto de palabras quiero quedarme con aquellas que contengan una suma de vocales par. Por ejemplo, la palabra "coche" tiene dos vocales, por tanto es válida.
El conjunto de palabras lo generé así:
shuf -n 20 /usr/share/dict/spanish > palabras.txt

Hasta ahí todo bien. Para seleccionar las que contengan un número de vocales par utilicé esta línea:
awk 'gsub(/[aeiouáéíóúAEIOUAÁÉÍÓÚ]/,"&")%2==0' palabras.txt

Y de hecho lo hace bien, salvo que se encuentre con una palabra como "acañutado"(no me juzguéis por esta palabra, la magia del azar). Tiene 5 vocales y sin embargo la deja pasar, cuando debería omitirla.
La varibale LC_ALL está con el valor es_ES.UTF-8, que es el valor por defecto en cualquier distro Ubuntu en español. No obstante con locale -a he podido comprobar que están cargados la mayoría de los locales en español.
Mi pregunta es: ¿por qué contabiliza esa palabra como válida cuando el número de vocales no es par? ¿Quizá la función gsub de awk no funciona bien con este tipo de carácteres?
Que conste que le pregunté a ChatGPT. Tras soltarme la tontería de turno preferí olvidar que estuve allí. Internet tampoco me aclaró gran cosa.
Gracias por adelantado.

Pues a mi me funciona bien. Algo se te está escapando en tu descripción que no sabemos. Cabe decir que mi locale es ca_ES.UTF-8 en todos excepto en el LC_ALL y el LANGUAGE que me aparecen vacios. Y mi locale -a no me muestra ni un es_ES.UTF-8, solo el ca_ES.UTF-8.

Tu código funciona sin problemas en mi caso en Arch Linux (que usa gawk por defecto) y es_ES.UTF-8 como locale.
La razón más simple que se me ocurre para explicar lo que te está pasando es que estés usando mawk como implementación de awk, lo que parece ser la opción por defecto en Ubuntu (no dispongo de Ubuntu localmente a mano, pero lo he comprobado en Google Colab, Ubuntu 22.04, y efectivamente usa mawk). Puedes comprobarlo con:
$ awk -W version

awk suele ser simplemente un enlace simbólico a gawk, mavk, etc.
mawk no soporta correctamente caracteres multibyte, como son el caso de todas nuestras vocales acentuadas y la ñ. Esto hace que trate a cada byte como un "carácter" independiente y tenemos esto:
$ printf "acañutado" | awk 'gsub(/[aeiouáéíóúAEIOUÁÉÍÓÚ]/, "-")'
-c--�-t-d-

un total de 6 coincidencias, una más de las esperadas porque el byte \xc3 que comparte tanto la ñ como el resto de vocales acentuadas es también tratado como una coincidencia. Esto también genera problemas con otras palabras sin la ñ de por medio:
$ printf "camión" | awk 'gsub(/[aeiouáéíóúAEIOUÁÉÍÓÚ]/, "-")'
c-m---n

ya que considera independientemente los dos bytes de la ó (\xc3\xb3) por lo que los reemplazos son 4 y no 3.
A diferencia de mawk, gawk (GNU Awk) tiene en cuenta la localización y soporta sin problemas los caracteres multibyte, esta es la salida en mi caso (gawk como implementación):
$ printf "acañutado" | awk 'gsub(/[aeiouáéíóúAEIOUÁÉÍÓÚ]/,"-")'
-c-ñ-t-d-

Lo más simple sería que usaras gawk explícitamente (instalando el paquete si no lo tienes):
$ gawk 'gsub(/[aeiouáéíóúAEIOUAÁÉÍÓÚ]/,"&")%2==0' palabras.txt

o cambiar la implementación por defecto de awk.

Mi ubuntu 22.04 usa gawk por defecto. Si fuerzo el mawk con esa instrucción efectivamente no sale bien.

FJSevilla, efectivamente en la versión de awk. Ubuntu (es una versión en Docker, no la versión oficial de Canonical) por defecto usa mawk y presenta los problemas que comentas. La solución es sin duda usar gawk. Agradezco tu aportación, me ha servido de muchísimo. Muchas gracias.

si esta en unicode ¿ya intentase buscar por ese caracter?
Por ejemplo:
gawk 'BEGIN{chartr = sprintf("%c", 0x0303)} index($0, chartr)'
Lo probe con un "more |" y funciona.
Espero te sea de utilidad

Hola Jorge, con gawk funciona correctamente. Gracias.
